# thumbnail helper fancybox v2.0.6

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using latest fancybox with thumbnail helper. It is working fine. I want to know if i can change thumbnail option. Currently Thumbnails position change when you click on any thumb. The flow is Left to right, if you go from first image to last. I want the thumbs to be fixed as align center. 
Does anyone know how to achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a custom thumbnailer script that I worked on. You'll need to edit the jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js in the helpers folder.

Change line 116 to:

```
this.list.width(this.width * (obj.group.length + 1)).css('left', Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - ((this.width * (obj.group.length) * 0.5))));
```

Then line 148 to:

```
'left': Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (this.width * (obj.group.length) * 0.5))
```

This should center the thumbs and remove the animation when changing images, while keeping the thumbs centered if you resize your window.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS compatibility, use @Scottorchard's answer with javascript's `window.innerWidth` property instead of `$(window).width()`:

**Line 116:**

```
this.list.width(this.width * (obj.group.length + 1)).css('left', Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.5 - ((this.width * (obj.group.length) * 0.5))));
```

**Line 148:**

```
'left': Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.5 - (this.width * (obj.group.length) * 0.5))
```

Comment: Update - this doesn't behave well with IE, so I ended up adding iOS sniffing like so:
`var theWidth = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i) ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();`

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a much simpler solution. Go into the CSS for the thumbnails and change the margin of the ul:

```
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

just like you would for any normal webpage. That worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing the scottorchard's answer (I can't make comments yet), if you want to change de css specifications of your thumb, pay attention at line 116:

The '3' means the border, and the '0.71' means the width size of your thumbs. After changing the css properties, you have to change this js line, too.

Mine is like this:

```
this.list.width(this.width * (obj.group.length + 3)).css('left', Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.71 - ((this.width * (obj.group.length) * 0.71))));
```

Answer (score 0):

replace #fancybox-thumbs ul

with

```
#fancybox-thumbs ul {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
left: 0 !important;
```

}